# Help needed to check if my solenoid wiring is correct

Tags: wires, teensy

I'm planning a new custom keyboard project which involves a solenoid being controlled by a Teensy2.0++, and i would like to power everything with just a USB cable.

I don't have much electronics or electrical engineering background but from my research, this is how I think i should be wiring my solenoid up.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me to check if this is correct and doesn't blow anything up.
[image: Schematics]

Comment: Your question is not really about arduino. But your wiring is correct if you get the transistor polarity right. You should also consider adding a pulldown at the base to avoid that the solenoid acts randomly on power-up/-down.

Comment: Add the pull down resistor at the port pin thereby eliminating a dividing network to the base.